# How do I "free look" in jets and helicopters?

Tags: battlefield-3

I saw a video on Youtube (not sure if it's OK to link it since it has NSFW language) of a player who was able to look around while in a jet using cockpit view. What key/button do you use to do this?

I'm personally interested in how to do this for Xbox 360, but it might be useful for others if anyone knows the answer for PS3 and PC as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On both the Xbox 360 and the PS3, press Down on the D-Pad to enter free look mode while piloting a jet or chopper.  You can change the camera mode by clicking the Right Stick.

I'm not sure about the PC version, there's a "toggle chase camera" option (default <kbd>C</kbd>) although I'm not sure how that compares to the console options.  tQuarella points out that holding the <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> button while moving the mouse will allow you to free look for as long as you hold the button down.

All of the (default) flight controls for the various vehicles on every platform is on [this page.](http://www.ign.com/wikis/battlefield-3/Flight_Controls)  The PC keyboard options seem like they must be incomplete, however.

Comment: With the PC version, holding right-click and moving the mouse will change your field of view while keeping the jet moving in the same direction.  When you release right-click, the field of view snaps back to center.

Comment: //// What's a D-pad on ps3?? ////

Comment: @Mike, On the PS3, the D-Pad is the four buttons in a cross or plus shape in the upper left hand part of the controller.  [Here is a picture.](http://i40.tinypic.com/2ns8ke9.jpg)