# How to freelook in cars on BF3, using XBOX 360?

Tags: battlefield-3

I'm not so sure of this since I play the game every 2 weeks or so, but I think there was a free look option on the jeep and other small cars, and I'm also not sure of this but there was also handbrake option on the cars on BF3, I  think these options were deleted after multiplayer update 3 or 4? help please

Comment: I don't know if you can or not. This [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43087/how-do-i-free-look-in-jets-and-helicopters) notes you press down on the D-Pad to enter free look mode in *aircraft*. I couldn't find anything related to jeeps

Comment: I also couldn't find anything related to a handbrake ever existing. I don't remember one

Answer (score 1):

To freelook in a car on BF3 Xbox version, simply move your right stick to look around. Same as you would as if you were a soldier.

Also, I don't believe a handbrake ever existed. The closest thing you can get to it will be tapping between the brakes and accelerator during a corner.